# Python Variable keeps resetting using actions.py

Tags: python-3.x

I guys. I have made an actions.py file with several classes. What Im trying to do is that I want a variable (in this case its called flag) I want to set it at zero as default and change it through the function. For some reason it keeps resetting flag to 0 when flag is used in another function.
`

```
from typing import Any, Text, Dict, List

from rasa_sdk import Action, Tracker
from rasa_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher

# Import the getData module to fetch the data.
from dbConnect import getData
import dbConnect
import mysql.connector
flag = 0

class FindByLocation(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_find_by_location"

    def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

    location = tracker.get_slot("location")
    price= tracker.get_slot("price")
    cuisine = tracker.get_slot("cuisine")
    print(location)
    # write the sql query here.
    query = "SELECT Name FROM Restaurant WHERE Location = '%s'" % location
    query3 = "SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM Restaurant WHERE Location = '%s' LIMIT 5" % location
    query2 = "CREATE VIEW LocationView AS SELECT RestaurantID, Name, PhoneNumber, Rating, PriceRange, Location, Sublocation FROM Restaurant WHERE Sublocation = '%s'"%(location)



    #pass the sql query to the getData method and store the results in `data` variable.
    var_location = getData(query)
    print(var_location)
    if not var_location:
        flag = 1
        var_sublocation = getData(query2)
        dispatcher.utter_message(text="یہ جگہ کس ایریا میں ہے")
    else:
        if cuisine is not None:
            count = getData(query3)
            dispatcher.utter_message(text="Find By Location",json_message=var_location)
            dispatcher.utter_message(text="Results found",json_message=count)
            dispatcher.utter_message(text="آپ کس پرائس میں کھانا پسند کریں گے")
        else:
            count = getData(query3)
            dispatcher.utter_message(text="Find By Location",json_message=var_location)
            dispatcher.utter_message(text="Results found",json_message=count)
            dispatcher.utter_message(text="آپ کس طرح کا کھانا پسند کریں گے؟")



        return[]


class FindBySublocation(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_find_by_sublocation"

def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:
    flag = 1
    print("FLAG VALUEEEEEE")
    print(flag)
    location = tracker.get_slot("location")
    query = "SELECT Name, Rating FROM LocationView WHERE Location = '%s'" % (location)
    query2 = "SELECT COUNT(Name), Rating FROM LocationView WHERE Location = '%s'" % (location)

    location = getData(query)
    location_count = getData(query2)
    dispatcher.utter_message(text="Sublocation Restaurants Found",json_message=location)
    dispatcher.utter_message(text="Results found",json_message=location_count)
    dispatcher.utter_message(text="آپ کس طرح کا کھانا پسند کریں گے؟")

    return[]


class FindByCuisineAndLocation(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_find_by_location_and_cuisine"

def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

    cuisine = tracker.get_slot("cuisine")
    location = tracker.get_slot("location")
    print(cuisine)
    print(location)
    print("flag value in Cuisine and Location")
    print(flag)
    # write the sql query here.
    if flag==0:
        query = "Select Name, Rating From Restaurant Where Location = '%s' AND RestaurantID IN (SELECT RestaurantID FROM Cuisine WHERE Name = '%s') LIMIT 5" % (location,cuisine)
        query2 = "Select COUNT(Name), Rating From Restaurant Where Location = '%s' AND RestaurantID IN (SELECT RestaurantID FROM Cuisine WHERE Name = '%s') LIMIT 5" % (location,cuisine)
    else:
        query = "Select Name, Rating From LocationView Where Location = '%s' AND RestaurantID IN (SELECT RestaurantID FROM Cuisine WHERE Name = '%s') LIMIT 5" % (location,cuisine)
        query2 = "Select COUNT(Name), Rating From LocationView Where Location = '%s' AND RestaurantID IN (SELECT RestaurantID FROM Cuisine WHERE Name = '%s') LIMIT 5" % (location,cuisine)

    #pass the sql query to the getData method and store the results in `data` variable.
    location_cuisine = getData(query)
    location_cuisine_count= getData(query2)

    print("data: ",location_cuisine)

    dispatcher.utter_message(text="Find By Cuisine And Location ",json_message=location_cuisine)
    dispatcher.utter_message(text="Number of places ",json_message=location_cuisine_count)
    dispatcher.utter_message(text="آپ کس پرائس میں کھانا پسند کریں گے")


    return []
```

By the time my flag which should be changed to 1 after being executed in Sublocation (which it does according to the terminal) it is changed to 0 when used again in any other function especially find_by_location_and_cuisine

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the global flag, use

```
global flag
```

in the function you want to use it.

If you don’t mention this statement, the `flag` variable is considered as a local variable, i.e., a new local variable is created.

Comment: I tried doing that as well but then I get an error saying flag is not defined in my action_find_by_location_and cuisine

Comment: I had to specifically use global variable in each method to call it. Thank you so much!